# Are we can send direct SOAP request from Standard PHP library functions In Sugar CRM7?

Tags: php, sugarcrm, soap-client, jasperserver, nusoap

I am working on integration of  Sugar CRM7 with *JasperReports Server* to fetch reports from Jasper report server. In which I use the standard PHP soap call function to send soap request that work accurately in my Sugar CRM7 on Local windows and Linux base server. But when I upload it to Live server environment then It is no working. I check all the dimensions of errors but does not identify this error. At the end I think this issue is due to sugar CRM7  permission to Direct Soap calls.

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('login' => $username, 'password' => $password,   "trace" => 1, "exceptions" => 0));

$request = "
<request operationName=\"runReport\" locale=\"en\">
    <argument name=\"RUN_OUTPUT_FORMAT\">$format</argument>
   <resourceDescriptor name=\"\" wsType=\"\" uriString=\"$report\" isNew=\"false\">
       <parameter name=\"account_id\" isForPrompting=\"false\" class=\"java.lang.String \">$account_id</parameter>
       <label>null</label>
       $imageURL
  </resourceDescriptor>
</request>";


$client->runReport($request);

echo $rbs = $client->__getLastResponse();
```

This is the code that work accurately in Local windows & Linux but not on Live server that is also on Linux.

Please guide me if I am missing some thing that going wrong

Comment: Do you really need to use SOAP? Jasperserver have REST API for any server side technology http://es.slideshare.net/mobile/marianolu/embedding-jaspersoft-into-your-php-application

Comment: They have example here: http://support.sugarcrm.com/04_Find_Answers/03_Developers/100Web_Services/100Soap_API/100Examples/100PHP/ Have you tried with that?